# Android: Is there a way to show "min" instead of "minute" with DateUtils

Tags: android, text, time, short, android-dateutils

I'm using DateUtils to show the posted time. But is there a way to show:

"4 min ago" instead of "4 minutes ago"

```
        CharSequence result = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(timestamp, Currenttime,DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
```

Comment: I think this post will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19409035/custom-format-for-relative-time-span

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use

```
 getRelativeTimeSpanString (long time, 
                long now, 
                long minResolution, 
                int flags)
```

and provide as `DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_RELATIVE` as flags.

Accordingly to the documentation

> Can use FORMAT_ABBREV_RELATIVE flag to use abbreviated relative times,
>   like "42 mins ago".

E.g.

```
CharSequence result = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(timestamp, Currenttime,DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS, DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_RELATIVE);
```

should do it.

Comment: You are a legend!