# Android getRelativeTimeSpanString not working

Tags: android, datetime

I am working on notifications and I need to display the time-> An action was performed in a way similar to ("5 seconds ago","12 mins ago","1 week ago" etc.)

This is the code I am using

```
     long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
     String datetime1 = "06/12/2015 03:58 PM";
     SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm aa");
     Date convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(datetime1);

     CharSequence relavetime1 = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
                            convertedDate.getTime(),
                            now,
                            DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS,
                            DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_RELATIVE);
```

And the result I get is

```
    relativetime1=June 12, 2015
```

The above obtained result doesn't seem like what its supposed to look like.

By searching online I've found that  if that duration is greater than a week, in which case it returns an ABSOLUTE 
-I don't quite understand what I found.

How do I achieve my requirement without using an external library?
Kindly help.

Comment: check this.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19409035/custom-format-for-relative-time-span

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?